# How to do “sequential” Job Scheduling (Quartz?)

Tags: java, scheduling, quartz-scheduler

I'm making use of Quartz Scheduling and there are 2 jobs. First Job is performing the tasks for around 2 minutes and the Second one is to be setup for Cleaning Operations of Temporary Files. So, I need to setup the Schedule to work in a way that after the first job is executed/finished performing tasks I need to do the cleaning operations with the help of Second Job.

Considering the Example 9 - Job Listeners under Quartz 2.1.x which states that we can define a method named jobWasExecuted( _, _ ); in the Job Listener and it executes when the 1st job is executed/or comes in running state. 

Are we able to setup the schedule which can listen for the first job finishing then executes second? or,

Are we able to define the join() method like in Java Multithreading which can execute on the completion of first job?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> There currently is no "direct" or "free" way to chain triggers with
>   Quartz. However there are several ways you can accomplish it without
>   much effort. Below is an outline of a couple approaches:
>
> One way is to use a listener (i.e. a TriggerListener, JobListener or
>   SchedulerListener) that can notice the completion of a job/trigger and
>   then immediately schedule a new trigger to fire. This approach can get
>   a bit involved, since you'll have to inform the listener which job
>   follows which - and you may need to worry about persistence of this
>   information.
>
> Another way is to build a Job that contains within its JobDataMap the name of the next job to fire, and as the job completes (the last step in its Execute() method) have the job schedule the next job. Several people are doing this and have had good luck. Most have made a base (abstract) class that is a Job that knows how to get the job name and group out of the JobDataMap using special keys (constants) and contains code to schedule the identified job. Then
>   they simply make extensions of this class that included the additional
>   work the job should do.

Ref: http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/faq.html#how-do-i-chain-job-execution?-or,-how-do-i-create-a-workflow?

Comment: Thanks Vishal the chaining of jobs seems to be what I need.

Answer (score 10):

I know this is an old question, but nevertheless there are 2 more options available to chain the execution of your jobs which people can find useful:

1) Use the [JobChainingJobListener](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/listeners/JobChainingJobListener.html) that is included in the standard Quartz distribution since very early releases. This listener allows you to programmatically define simple job chains using its *[addJobChainLink](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/listeners/JobChainingJobListener.html#addJobChainLink(org.quartz.JobKey,%20org.quartz.JobKey))* method.

2) Use a commercial solution such as [QuartzDesk](https://www.quartzdesk.com/documentation/features#job-chaining) that I am the principal developer of. QuartzDesk contains a robust job chaining engine that allows you to externalize the definition of your job chains from the application code and enables you to update your job chains at runtime through a GUI without modifying, redeploying and restarting your application. A job chain can be associated with a particular job, trigger or it can be a global job chain that is executed whenever any of your jobs execute (useful for global job execution failure handlers etc.).

[image: QuartzDesk GUI: Editing a job chain target]

Answer (score -2):

From http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/faq.html#how-do-i-chain-job-execution?-or,-how-do-i-create-a-workflow

> How do I keep a Job from firing concurrently?
>
> **Quartz.NET 2.x**
>
> Implement IJob and also decorate your job class with
>   [DisallowConcurrentExecution] attribute. Read the API documentation
>   for DisallowConcurrentExecutionAttribute for more information.

The annotation is available in the Java implementation.