# Quartz .Net execute JobA always before JobB

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I have a situation.
Currently i have 2 Jobs

JobA: Gets List of fileNames and Saves them to a location on the server.
JobB: Gets fileName parameter from JobDetail instance and retrieve this saved File and sends an email.

For JobB, i have multiple instances running with different triggers.

To email latest file, i want JobA instance to Run once before all JobB instances are fired.

So lets say there are 5 instances of jobB having same trigger and with 3 of them having 'aaa.pdf' and 2 of them 'abc.pdf' as parameters.

So for this trigger i want JobA to run once and download these 2 files 'aaa.pdf' and 'abc.pdf' and then these 5 instances of JobB should be triggered

lets say JobB1 is about to trigger with parameter 'aaa.pdf' and JobB2 is about to trigger with parameter 'abc.pdf'. Here JobB1 and JobB2 are instances of JobB. I want JobA to run with array parameter ['aaa.pdf', 'abc.pdf'] and then JobB1 , JobB2 concurrently ...

Please suggest/correct me the approach.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do “sequential” Job Scheduling (Quartz?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13486607/how-to-do-sequential-job-scheduling-quartz)

Comment: You might want to have a look at job listeners https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/faq.html How do I chain Job execution?

Comment: lets say JobB1 is about to trigger with parameter 'aaa.pdf' and JobB2 is about to trigger with parameter 'abc.pdf'. Here JobB1 and JobB2 are instances of JobB. I want JobA to run with array parameter ['aaa.pdf', 'abc.pdf'] and then JobB1 , JobB2 concurrently ...

Comment: I think it is possible to achieve what you want with job listeners. But maybe you don't want to implement it with jobs and quartz? Maybe you schedule single job and download/process files in parallel in it?

Comment: At a given time JobB can have n (unknown) instances being triggered all/some with different filenames. Job A needs to run first with all these filenames as param array to download/process file and then instances of jobB can be run.... being fairly new to quartz i am confused with my scenario and what quartz can offer

Comment: Why do you need quartz for the task in a first place?

Comment: i am using windows service with Quartz.net to run the jobs automatically on the server and my jobB triggers may be little complicated and thought of using CRON triggers as well

Comment: That makes sense, I already mentioned, that for you task it might be enough to schedule one job and implement all related logic there. Also you might be interested in NServiceBus or MassTransit which can help in building beter workflow solutions.