# Scheduling tasks in spring boot one after another

Tags: spring-boot, scheduling

I am trying to have scheduling in my spring boot application, I am already using scheduler with cron expression but the problem is that I have about five scheduler in which I need to schedule the first three scheduler tasks to run once in a day and the rest of which runs after executing these two tasks.

The problem is that when the first scheduler running for some time the second one scheduler starts when its time reaches and it makes misunderstandings because both tasks are using the same database as well as same table. I want to process a record only once e.g if any scheduler process a record will not be processed by any other scheduler that day. So now I want to schedule these tasks in a sequence when the first one completes the execution then the second one will be starts and so on.

Comment: Have you tried using quartz. This gives you much more control of what you are doing through jobs triggers and scheduler.

Comment: no don't tried yet, needs to check

Comment: this might help [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13486882/3359134)

Comment: I also want to process a record uniquely means when a record once process by any thread or scheduler will not be processed by any other thread that day.